# I have two models that depend on each other to be valid. How do I create valid factories for them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a `Survey` model and `Question` model as below. `Survey` must have a minimum of 1 `Question` and `Question` must belong to a `Survey` shown below:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, class_name: 'Question', inverse_of: :survey

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates_length_of :questions, maximum: 100, minimum: 1
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey, class_name: 'Survey', inverse_of: :questions

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :survey, presence: true
end
```

When I write the factories, such as below, I will get a StackOverflow error since a Survey will build a Question after creation and Question will build a Survey after creation, leading to an infinite loop.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :question, class: Question do
    association :survey, factory: :survey
    title  { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }

  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :aya_pg_portfolio_survey_survey, class: Survey do
    after(:build) do |survey|
      survey.questions = build_list(question, 5)
    end

    title { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
  end
end
```

I then thought to remove either the Survey association in the Question factory or remove the `after(:build)` call back in the Survey factory. This however will result in invalid factories.

There seems like there should be an easy way to solve this since all I have are two models that simple require the other but I am stuck...

Comment: I wonder if a circular dependency like this is a good idea?

Comment: `survey.questions = build_list(question, 5, survey: nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have the survey factory point to a question factory without a survey factory?

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :question do
    title  { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
    survey nil

    factory :question_and_survey do
      survey
    end
  end
end
```

This does mean that this `create(:question_and_survey)` would return a question in a survey with 6 total questions in it. Better than nothing, right?

But as commented on your question, you really should consider allowing an empty survey to be created. It's just a lot less hair pulling.

[Reference to inheritance in factorybot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance)

Comment: `But as commented on your question, you really should consider allowing an empty survey to be created. It's just a lot less hair pulling.` -> Was ultimately the best solution.